# incompatible types: List<Integer> cannot be converted to ArrayList<Integer> for Java sublists

Tags: java, arraylist

I have been having this issue which I am not able to resolve at the moment. It is a type mismatch between List and ArrayList. I am not too sure of what went wrong with my work. Any help will be appreciated.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
    // Sum of array
    static Integer sumArray(ArrayList<Integer> Array){
        Integer sum=Integer.valueOf(0);
        for(int i=0;i<Array.size();i++){
            sum+=Array.get(i);
        }
        return sum;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ArrayList<Integer> RideArr = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // Initializing array
        // Print out the RideArr values in list format(~)

        RideArr.add(1);
        RideArr.add(2);
        RideArr.add(3);
        RideArr.add(4);
        RideArr.add(5);
        ArrayList<Integer> jack=RideArr.subList(0, 4);
        System.out.println(sumArray(jack));
    }
}
```

> Error: incompatible types: List cannot be converted to
> ArrayList
> ArrayList jack=RideArr.subList(0, 4);

Comment: `jack=new ArrayList(RideArr.sbList(0,4))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of a variable should pretty much never be `ArrayList`. ArrayList is one specific kind of list implementation. `someList.subList(a, b)` **does not return an ArrayList**. It returns a List just fine, it's just not exactly an arraylist. Even ArrayList's own subList does not, itself, return an ArrayList.

It shouldn't matter what the implementation is, hence, using `ArrayList` anywhere is wrong; except with `new ArrayList`, as you can't write `new List` - with `new`, that is the one time you need to tell java what kind of list implementation you want. Thus:

```
List<Integer> rideArr = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> jack = rideArr.subList(0, 4);
```

NB: We write `TypesLikeThis` and `variablesLikeThis`, so, `rideArr`, not `RideArr`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one:

```
ArrayList<Integer> jack = new ArrayList<>(RideArr.subList(0,4));
System.out.println(sumArray(jack));
```